# how to change image(img URL is everytime coming from the server) on button click in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in client side scripting as well as stackoverflow. I want to change an image(Image URL is coming from the server everytime) of a div on click of a button or anchor. Here is My code for changing image.

```
$scope.captchaChange = function () {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/Project/captcha/captcha',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        if (response.imgUrl.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("captchaImg").src = response.imgUrl;
            document.getElementById("captchatext").value = response.imgToken;
        } else {
            alert('no captcha Image Avalable');
        }
    }).error(function (response) {
        //alert("response" + response)
        $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: If I get your question correct, you want to load a new image from the server and place it into the div?

Comment: I see `$scope, $http`, if you are using angular? Do it using angular way

Comment: @Satpal , yes iam using it but i am new with it, can u tell me how to do in angularjs. thank you

Comment: @user3117914, post you html template as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to load a new image from the server and replace the current image in the div, you can do it like this:

```
 $('#img-change-btn').click(function() {
    var path = response.imgUrl // Or some path;
    $('#img-display-div img').attr('src', path)
                         .attr('alt', $('img', this).attr('title')); 
});
```

Here's working code: http://jsfiddle.net/yV6e6/6/

Note: I've used a bit of JQuery (.click, .empty,.append, etc), you can remove that and use only Javascript if you aren't using the JQuery Library.

Comment: yes, I checked it, there is no error, path for new image is coming but image is not being changed. empity() function is working fine but append() is not. but on page refresh its working fine.

Comment: Actually, in server side at run tym i m generating one captcha image, and sending the path of that img and putting that path in the src attribute of img but its not working.
But, if i am doing the same thing with already existing image(at the server) then its working fine

Comment: A few things: 1.Make sure you're sending the URL to the image and not the filesystem path; 2. Make sure the image is generated and stored on the server before sending the URL to the client JS.

Comment: Hey Joshua ,,, i hav done it.... now its working fine... this was server side problem, everytime i was generating image with same name so it was not showing the new image, but now everytime I am generating the image with diffrent name and its working fine... Thank u..

Comment: Kool, no need to thank me, give yourself a pat on the back for figuring it out :).